# Tomcat webdav behind IIS Reverse proxy

Tags: iis, webdav, tomcat9

I have a java application running on tomcat http://testwebsit:8080/Application I configured the IIS reverse proxy by adding an inboard rule using URL rewrite feature and now I am able to access the application http://testwebsit/Application as expected

however, the WebDAV not working as expected after I did the above changes could you please advise on the above, and is it mandatory to define any outboard rule?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules You have to use things like FRT to analyze how WebDAV requests fail. Merely saying "not working" makes it a question impossible to discuss further.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how WebDAV doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The IIS is not a best option, usually nginx is used as a reverse proxy.
It would be easier to you to find docs.
Also the Tomcat is probably not a best option too. The de facto standard in Apache Httpd.
The Windows mount webdav folder also works not so stable.
You can debug with Wireshark to see what really happens.